# Axios: Network Error with Nuxtjs and Php api

Tags: php, api, nuxt.js

i use Axios in Nuxtjs.
when i want to get data from php api returns "Network Error".

```
 axios.get('https://joozveh.ir/api/test.php')
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
```

and php test code:

```
$data = array("id"=>1,"name"=>"ali");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: the given url does not exist

Comment: Was edited @RamRaider